# How to measure the replication in PostgreSQL with Grafana

Tags: postgresql, prometheus, grafana

I’m looking for a way to monitor in graphana replication among the nodes of a PostgreSQL cluster.

I have been reviewing and my version has the following options available:

pg_stat_replication_reply_time
pg_stat_replication_pg_wal_lsn_diff
pg_stat_replication_pg_current_wal_lsn_bytes

Currently I'm working with the pg_stat_replication_reply_time metric which according to what I have researched measures the time it takes to write from the primary node to the standby.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/daN8G.png)

It's the first time that I work with these monitoring tools, can you advise me about the metric I'm using is correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I personally prefer using `pg_stat_replication_pg_wal_lsn_diff` gauge. It shows how far (in bytes) a replica is behind the master. You don't need any functions to use it, just put the name into the query box

```
pg_stat_replication_pg_wal_lsn_diff
# or, if you have variables
pg_stat_replication_pg_wal_lsn_diff{instance="$instance"}
```

As for the other metrics you mentioned, here's what I know:

- `pg_stat_replication_pg_current_wal_lsn_bytes` - metric description says it's "WAL position in bytes". I guess if you subtract the value of a master server from the value of a replica, the result should be identical to `pg_stat_replication_pg_wal_lsn_diff`.
- `pg_stat_replication_reply_time` - metric description says it's "Unknown metric from pg_stat_replication", but actually it is mentioned in [PostgreSQL docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/monitoring-stats.html#MONITORING-PG-STAT-REPLICATION-VIEW):

  > `reply_time` timestamp with time zone
  >
  > Send time of last reply message received from standby server

  What does that "reply message" mean (in which situation it is sent) I don't know, so I stick to using bytes instead. However if you wish to use it then since it's a timestamp, you need a query like this:

  ```
  time() - pg_stat_replication_reply_time
  ```

  You can also apply `rate()` instead and if everything's OK the result should be a straight line with the value close to 1 (because `rate()` calculates a per-second increase of a counter). In my experience this thing does not work properly with WAL-consumers other than PostgreSQL (e.g. Debezium), while `pg_stat_replication_pg_wal_lsn_diff` remains to work as intended.

Comment: Thanks for your comment,  it's really useful for me